# Mongoose.populate() returns empty array instead of data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I've looked up other questions including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118092/mongoose-populate-returning-empty-array) however I couldn't find an answer resolves my problem.

I have defined my models in the same way described in [official documentation of mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) by showing references and defining types of models as *Schema.Types.ObjectId*. Here they are:

**story_model.js**

```
var storySchema = new Schema({
    ...
    candidateParts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'StoryPart'}],
    ...
}, { usePushEach: true});
```

**storyPart_model.js**

```
var storyPartSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    storyId: { type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' },
    ...
}, { usePushEach: true});
```

And, I have built a query like that where `ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;` and `storyModel` is Story passed through storyController.js

Here is how I call populate:

```
StoryController.prototype.getCandidateParts = function (storyId, callback) {
var me = this;
const id = { '_id': ObjectID(storyId) };
me.storyModel.findOne(id).populate('candidateParts').exec(function(err,story) {
    if (err) return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({ success: false, extras: { message: me.ApiMessages.DB_ERROR }}));
    if (story) {
        return callback(err, story);
    }else {
        return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({ success: false, extras : { message: me.ApiMessages.STORY_NOT_EXISTS }}));
    }
});
};
```

Following is how I check results of my new populated story:

```
me.getCandidateParts(story._id, (err, populatedStory) => {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }
        if (populatedStory) {
            console.log(populatedStory);
```

But I get this result instead of story with populated parts:

```
[ { _id: 5a8bfaab78798703c0760bd1,
__v: 2,
is_updated: 2018-02-20T10:38:32.620Z,
is_created: 2018-02-20T10:38:32.620Z,
candidateParts: []
... } ]
```

By the way, I'm sure candidateParts include in database something like that:

```
ObjectId("5a8bfa33cd601903b57329ab")
```

And yes, I'm also sure that I have defined model references with exactly the same identifiers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you remove the `.populate('candidateParts')` part, does the result logged in `console.log(populatedStory)` have anything in the `candidateParts` array?

Comment: @chridam yes, id of part returns like that `[ 5a8c2df95eb65602b02e0687 ]`

Comment: And if you query the `storyparts` collection in mongo shell with that id e.g `db.storyparts.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a8c2df95eb65602b02e0687") })` do you get any document as a result?

Comment: @chridam I have found I had same ID for StoryPart and Story instances. I should have something wrong during saving new parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that somehow I have **same ID** for StoryPart and Story instances. That's why it returns nothing.

**EDIT:**

I have resolved the problem by ensuring and correcting IDs of story and storypart. I do not delete the question since there might be people facing the same problem, 
so just **check your ObjectIDs if they refer to correct instances**.